# How to setup Free shipping promotion rule for only products from specific categories over $200

Tags: magento-1, free-shipping

Row total from only eligible categories should be considered for the $200. .row  totals from other categories should not be added for $200 calculations

Comment: can you please explain your question more in details. what is exactly $200 ?

Answer (score 2):

Free shipping when the subtotal is greater than $200 is pretty easy to set up.

To configure your shopping cart rule, go to `Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rule`. Then click on `Add New Rule` and start to fill in the general information like name etc.

In the tab `Conditions` you will have to configure that the subtotal should be above 200 USD

Conditions of a shopping cart price rule with **subtotal equal or greater than 200 USD

***Short:***

**Actions** should be:
`Subtotal equal or greater than 200 USD`

**Conditions**
Free Shipping: For matching items only
Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions: Your categories you want to discount

---

A bit of explanation...

The tab `Actions` will allow you to grant free shipment. The label `Free Shipping` has three values:

1. No
2. For matching items only
3. For shipment with matching items
   In the tab ‘actions’ you are able to give free shipping

The first option will prevent giving free shipping. The second option will only give free shipment to the items that match the conditions you list in the block titled Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions.If you choose all then every product will have free shipping.

Using these matching conditions you can for example restrict free shipping to product of preselected categories: If you say category is XX or YY then these get free shipping. Products from other categories are still included in the shipment cost calculation.

The third option “shipment with matching items” will give free shipment to orders that contain matching items listed in the block titled “Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions”. In the above example: if I have a product from category XX, my whole order will obtain free shipping even if I have products from another category.

Comment: Thanks Klettseb , I believe  above solution will also include the total from not eligible categories too for the $200 limit . Our requirement is to consider only eligible categories for considering $200 limit

Comment: You have to add them under conditions